# Variables are being ignored using the Twig Include template tag

Tags: symfony, twig

I have setup the following:

```
{% include '_elements/page-heading.html' with {'shortTitle': 'entry.shortTitle','title':'entry.title'} %}
```

However, when the page renders this template it is actually outputting "entry.shortTitle" in the page when it should surely actually know what the entry.title is for this page.

e.g. it should say "Latest News" not "entry.title".

Just wondering why this would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclosing `entry.shortTitle` with (single) quotes tells Twig that this simply is a string. When you want to pass the value of a variable, you have to leave away the quotes:

```
{% include '_elements/page-heading.html' with { 'shortTitle': entry.shortTitle, 'title': entry.title } %}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Of course. It's always the stupid stuff... How embarrassing...

Thanks!